# Pythagorean Primes

Tags: prime-numbers, gaussian-integers

A Pythagorean prime number $c$ can be expressed as the sum of two squares; that is
$a^2 + b^2 = c$ is a Pythagorean prime number when $c$ is prime.

What is the highest known Pythagorean prime number?

Comment: Please be more exact. Every prime c with $c\equiv 1 \pmod 4$ is a sum of two squares. Do you mean prime a,b?

Answer (score 2):

The largest known primes are tabulated [here](http://primes.utm.edu/primes/search.php?Number=100). $19249*2^{13018586}+1$ is the biggest one congruent 1 modulo 4, so it's the biggest known prime sum of two squares.

EDIT: That website now gives a bigger prime congruent 1 modulo 4: $10223*2^{31172165}+1$.

Comment: Thank you to Gerry Myerson. You answered the question.

Comment: The way to acknowledge that a question has been answered to your satisfaction, is to click in the check mark next to the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is not highest Pythagorean Prime because of what gammatester said,Every prime c with c≡1(mod4) is a sum of two squares. You can infinitely find larger and larger primes of this type.

Your question must be,which is the largest Pythagorean prime number that has been ever computed.

Answer: Only  Computer knows.

Comment: You can infinitely find larger and larger primes of this type. Link to proof please?

Note that the converse is also true; all Pythagorean primes are congruent to 1 mod 4. These two statements combined are [Fermat's theorem on the sums of two squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares)